# Inserting <a> tag in database output in R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, sqldf

My effort to display all desired lines in data-set is:

```
observeEvent (input$uploadForTest_1, {
      ....
       ....
    ab <- sprintf("select * from file where V1='%s'", tmp)
    res <- read.csv.sql(file,header=FALSE,sql = ab,tmp,sep="\t")
    print(res)      
)}
```

This is giving me desired output and code is running absolutely fine. i.e.

```
25 b093.wav street 126.840270 134.57507              car
26 b093.wav street 127.101581 135.34158  people speaking
27 b093.wav street 134.575070 158.01465              car
```

I want that by clicking on `b093.wav` in `Line No. 25`, corresponding `col4` and `col5` integer values should be stored in some variables. I think that this will be done by using anchor tag `<a>`. But is it possible to link `<a>` with database output? I didn't find any way of doing this? Anyone know how can I solve my problem?

Comment: [DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) package might be helpful?

Comment: @zx8754I found no help form this.

Comment: @zx8754 do you have solution to this problem?